# Github & Trello lists

Tags: list, github, trello

I'm working on a project that's just about done.
Now I just need a list that shows all the things I've worked on. Luckily I've been using Github and [Trello](https://trello.com/) to keep track of all my work.

Does anyone know how to get a simple list of commits/activities from any of these 2 services?
I just need a simple list like this:

Date: 
Title: 
Description:

I'm working on a Mac but I'm using the Github client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github: In the terminal, you can navigate to the folder that you are working in and type `git log`. It will give you a list of commits. If you would like to save it in a text file you could type`git log > commits.txt`.
Trello: In Trello you can go to the board you are working on and select print form the menu. This will give you a list of activities.

Comment: I have 0 experience working with the terminal. How would I go to the folder?

Comment: And what menu in trello? I can press cmd+p but that doesn't let me save anything.

Comment: Nvm, I managed to figure it out. Thanks for the help :)